# $k$-th derivative of an exponantial function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, induction, exponential-function, exponentiation

How do I derive this $k$-th derivative:
$\dfrac{d^k}{dt^k}e^{tx}=x^ke^{tx}?$

I believe that induction is to be used.

Comment: Induction is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Induction will work great, but I'll mention that you might be getting a bit confused or distracted by the variables they chose to use. I'm curious if you find

$$\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{ax}=a^n e^{ax}$$

a bit more obvious. Because it's the exact same thing as your question.

Comment: Right, but I cannot make formally the induction argument!

Comment: You should add a "what I've done so far" section to your question, and tell us where you've gotten stuck.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I have done it for $n=1$ but not for $n+1$. I'm confused with the data obtained.

Comment: Do you know how to use induction in other cases, or is induction a problem for you generally?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC A problem from high school. But I can imagine what's going on here by now.

Comment: Heh. Okay, well, good luck. You can update your question later if you want people to check the work you've done.